# Change all data in a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the data in one row of a table.  Long story short I moved some files around and I need to change the pointer so they are all the same...

So I have Service_ID with 2 options 5 or 1 I want to change them so they all are 1

I am not sure how to accomplish this and could use some pointers.  I do have access to the MySQL Console as well as PHPMyAdmin

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to say here

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET Service_ID=1 WHERE Service_ID=5`??? Don't run it yet though, make sure this is what you want on some test data

Comment: To elaborate on @CodeBird 's comment, run a `Select * from table_name where service_id = 5` and confirm if those are the records which you need to change the service id to 1. If yes, then run his command

Answer (score 0):

Changes row with service_id=5 to 1

```
Update tableName
Set Service_ID=1
Where Service_ID=5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table SET service_id = 1
```

This will change every row to `service_id` = 1

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes to mark this as correct - but until then, THANK YOU!